# Adobe Media Server Alternative for VideoChat

Tags: air, adobe, h.264, flash-media-server, videochat

I currently have a video chat app working on web(Flash) and android via Adobe AIR, it uses Adobe Media Server (RTMP) as backend for video streaming and shared objects, my question is, if there is another server or solution that provides many to many live video broadcast maybe using H.264 codec from android and iOS, have some sort of user list and room list stored in a database or similar, I want to move away from Adobe as it has many limitations on mobile devices.
Live video is crucial in 1 to many broadcasts that will have hundreds of viewers at the same time.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as today, we have decided that we can manage the users,rooms and messages via [Google Firebase Real Time Database](https://firebase.google.com/), and the live video stream using [ANT Media Server](https://antmedia.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Ulex.fr created an RTMP connector for Asterisk (the free PBX platform).
Used with the Asterisk Vonference application, it allows you to create conference rooms for 1 to many configuration, with audio and video. The only one limitation is the power of your server. You can plan a scalable architecure in order to broadcast one video to many (many could be unlimited). We developp a specific protocol to connect and manage the connection based on the telephony events. I think we already done a direct RTMP connection that skip this protocol too.

All the project done by ulex.fr is free, OpenSource and GPL.

Get the full project here :  https://github.com/voximal/asterisk-rtmp

(a live demo is available)

We already develop an RTMP stack for android with video (using the camera), this allows you to create your own application without using AIR.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Adobe Cirrus, it's still in the beta stage (actually IMHO Adobe forgot about it), but it works on web, desktop and mobile too. Check this Video Phone example, it can handle chat applications without a problem.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Red5 Media Server](http://red5.org), which is an open source solution. There are other options like the [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com)'s solutions on AWS, but they come a  higher cost...